# Connect HP (Enterprise) MFCs to Google Secure LDAP

Tags: ldap, multi-function-printer, hp

HP Enterprise MFCs running FutureSmart Firmware 3/4/5 support connecting to an LDAP server to retrieve email addresses for the Address Book (as well as printer user login, etc).

Google supports Secure LDAP with Client Certificate authentication. Username/password authentication is optional, but the client must use a certificate.

FutureSmart 5 doesn't seem to have a way of setting certificate authentication in the LDAP settings, but does have a general certificates management console.

Does anyone know how to connect a HP printer directly to Google LDAP?

Failing that, it looks like I have to set up an OpenLDAP server running as Proxy to translate the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working at all ?

Google suggests using a Stunnel which is the same idea as your openLDAP.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?hl=en#basic-instructions

Optional: Use stunnel as a proxy
For clients that don't offer a way to authenticate to LDAP with a client certificate, use stunnel as a proxy.

Configure stunnel to provide the client certificate to the LDAP server and configure your client to connect to stunnel. Ideally, you'll run stunnel on the same server(s) as your application and only listen locally so that you don't expose your LDAP directory beyond that server.

Follow these steps:

Install stunnel. For example, on Ubuntu:

```
$  sudo apt-get install stunnel4
```

Create a configuration file /etc/stunnel/google-ldap.conf with the following contents (assuming ldap-client.crt is the cert, and ldap-client.key is the key):

```
[ldap]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:1636
connect = ldap.google.com:636
cert = ldap-client.crt
key = ldap-client.key
```

To enable stunnel, edit `/etc/default/stunnel4` and set `ENABLED=1`.
Restart stunnel.

```
$  sudo /etc/init.d/stunnel4 restart
```

Configure your application to point to `ldap://127.0.0.1:1636`.

You can replace “1636” with any unused port if you also change the accept line in the configuration file above. You'll need to use plaintext LDAP without StartTLS/SSL/TLS enabled between the client and stunnel, since they are communicating locally.
Note: If you choose to run stunnel on a separate server, you must configure your firewalls so that only the necessary applications can access your stunnel server. You can also configure stunnel to listen with TLS so that data between your application and stunnel servers is encrypted. The details of both of these configurations depend on your environment.

Comment: Nope, too many of my clients are 100% cloud so don't have an on site server that could run a proxy 24/7, I've have to launch something in the cloud myself and then on bill it. Then just generally trying to keep up with the work got in the way of building scalable robust self maintaining systems. I'll have to revisit this in the future. Unfortunately O365 has a worse issue where they don't even offer LDAP with Premium, you have to buy Azure P2 licences or something to get LDAP, so again, no printer address book syncing.

Comment: @Dom jumpcloud or similar might be your answer,  or openldap running on AWS.